# Bind MvxBindableTableViewCell's Accessory to boolean

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm stuck on how to bind the MvxBindableTableViewCell's accessory to a boolean.

I have the table's ItemsSource bound to a list in my ViewModel, showing a nice list of clickable items.

However I want the cell's accessory (UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark) to show only when this object is flagged. By flagged I mean a boolean in the model is set to true.

Does anyone know how to bind the cell's accessory?

EDIT:
I can show the Accessory depending on the model's boolean, but it's not bound.

```
protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath     indexPath, object item)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new PlotsTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, CellIdentifier);

        Plot p = (Plot)item;
        if (p.Done)
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can probably do this in your PlotsTableViewCell.

If you declare a custom cell, then you can bind within that cell at runtime.

You can see an example of this in: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch/Cells/SessionCell2.cs which is used in the sessions display:

[image: Cell]

You can see that the cell provides public properties like:

```
public string RoomText
    {
    get { return Label2.Text; }
    set { if (Label2 != null) Label2.Text = value; }
    }
```

and then provides binding text like:

```
    'RoomText':{'Path':'Item.Session','Converter':'SessionSmallDetails','ConverterParameter':'SmallDetailsFormat'},
```

For binding an Accessory to a Bool, you should be able to do something like:

```
public bool IsDone
    {
    get { return Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark; }
    set 
    {
        if (value) 
        {
            Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark; 
        }
        else 
        {
            Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None; 
        }
    }
    }
```

with text:

```
    'IsDone':{'Path':'Done'},
```

---

As an advanced technique, you could also use a custom image inside a custom drawn button instead of an Accessory in your cell. To see how to do this, take a look at how the `IsFavorite` property is bound in that conference sample - see the two way custom bindings in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch/Bindings

Comment: Stuart, you're awesome! Go make a dinosaur badge for yourself! I've successfully bound the boolean to the cell's accessory using the code above. As for the advanced technique, the accessory is exactly what I was looking for (in this case).

Comment: thanks. Also please be sure to test on real hardware - i think accessory is one thing I've seen the linker remove - so you may need to include a LinkerIncludePlease dummy file to trick the linker

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, I know where to find the a LinkerInclude example ;)